# Wordpress Permalinks: Remove tag base and add the .html extension

Tags: php, wordpress, mod-rewrite, permalinks

### My question:

`My permalink settings:`

**General settings> Custom > /%postname%.html**

**Optional settings> Tag base > tag**

---

I want to like this: `mysite.com/%tag-slug%.html`

*Thanks*

---

### Edited for @Dimitry

was exactly the way I want

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Custom tag URLs
Description: Appends .html to tag links
*/

// applied when calling get_tag_link()
add_filter('tag_link', 'my_tag_link', 10, 2);

/**
 * Returns a link to a tag. Instead of /tag/tag-name/ returns /tag-name.html
 */
function my_tag_link($tag_link, $tag_id) {
    $tag_base = get_option('tag_base');
    if ($tag_base) {
        // problem. returning: http://www.domain.com/post-tag/tag-name
        //$tag_link = preg_replace('@^' . preg_quote($tag_base, '@') . '@', '', $tag_link);

        // I added it. Result: http://www.domain.com/tag-name
        $tag_link = str_replace("$tag_base/", "", preg_replace('@^' . preg_quote($tag_base, '@') . '@', '', $tag_link)); 
        //echo "$tag_link<br>";
    }
    // problem. returning: http://www.domain.com/http://www.domain.com/tag-name.html
    //return '/' . trim($tag_link, '/') . '.html';

    // I added it. Result: http://www.domain.com/tag-name.html , 
    return trim($tag_link, '/') . '.html';

}
?>
```

**I did the permalink settings**

General settings> Custom > /post-%postname%.html
Optional settings> Tag base > post-tag

**.htaccess:**

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

# Rewrites /tag-name.html as /post-tag/tag-name
# Assuming that your tag_base option is blank or set to 'post-tag'
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/post-.*
RewriteRule ^/?([^/]*)\.html$ /post-tag/$1
```

Single pages: http://www.domain.com/post-hello-world.html >> is working
Tag Pages   : http://www.domain.com/tag-name.html >> Not found 404
              http://www.domain.com/post-tag/tag-name >> working

**Problem:**

Tag pages can not be found

*I'm sorry. I am beginner. Thank you Dimitry*

Comment: I guess a wordpress forum would lead to better results... the question is maybe a bit too localized and not strictly a programming question.

Comment: So you want your posts to be referenced by their tag + .html? Or do you want tags to end in '.html'?

Comment: I want this thing;
Tags page url: mysite.com/tag-slug.html    
Post page url: mysite.com/post-slug.html
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure there is anything you can do through the admin interface, but you can add a little of your own code as a plugin (inside wp-content/plugins/tag_links.php):

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Custom tag URLs
Description: Appends .html to tag links
*/

// applied when calling get_tag_link()
add_filter('tag_link', 'my_tag_link', 10, 2);

/**
 * Returns a link to a tag. Instead of /tag/tag-name/ returns /tag-name.html
 */
function my_tag_link($tag_link, $tag_id) {
    $tag_base = get_option('tag_base');
    if ($tag_base) {
        $tag_link = preg_replace('@^' . preg_quote($tag_base, '@') . '@', '', $tag_link); 
    }
    return '/' . trim($tag_link, '/') . '.html';
}
```

And in your .htaccess file, above other rewrite rules, do something like:

```
# Rewrites /tag-name.html as /post-tag/tag-name
# Assuming that your tag_base option is blank or set to 'post-tag'
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/post-.*
RewriteRule ^/?([^/]*)\.html$ /post-tag/$1
```

And your post URL structure would be post-%postname%.html.

All this to say that your tags and posts must have at least one differentiating feature in the URL structure. In this case, it's the 'post-' prefix for post URLs.

Are you building a Wiki?

Comment: Thanks for your long reply.Everything is working correctly.But there are some problems. I have edited my question. Please check. Thanks.

Comment: Hey John. The htaccess rules I gave have to go between RewriteBase and the first RewriteRule.

Comment: @Dimitry I did. but I do not know, Right?. Tag pages is still not working(error 404). 


[new htaccess](http://img219.imageshack.us/i/htaccess.jpg/)

Comment: @John, seems the solution requires more than simple mod_rewrites. I would look into adding rules to the rewrite module: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/WP_Rewrite

Comment: @Dimitry I did. Its running. Thank you for all the things.

add_filter('tag_rewrite_rules', 'my_func');

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if im wrong, but I think that can NOT be done because of duplicate content.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Try this http://wordpress.org/plugins/import-html-pages/

mports well-formed static HTML files into WordPress. Requires PHP 5.

This plugin will import a directory of files as either pages or posts. You may specify the HTML tag (e.g. , , or ) or Dreamweaver template region (e.g. 'Main Content') containing the content you want to import.

If importing pages, the directory hierarchy will be preserved. Directories containing the specified file types will be imported as empty parent pages (or, if an index file is present, its contents will be used for the parent page). Directories that do not contain the specified file types will be ignored.

As files are imported, the resulting IDs, permalinks, and titles will be displayed. On completion, the importer will provide a list of Apache redirects that can be used in your .htaccess file to seamlessly transfer visitors from the old file locations to the new WordPress permalinks. As of 2.0, if you change your permalink structure after you've imported your files, you can regenerate the redirects—the file's old URL is stored as a custom field in the imported post.